# How do you find the KL Divergence between two multi-variable datasets?

Tags: probability, distributions, kullback-leibler, divergence, concept-drift

### Background

I'm working on a tabular data model that performs a binary classification. The model has recently started underperforming and I'd like to know if that's due to a drift in the feature distribution of the model.

The features in the model haven't changed. The model hasn't been retrained. There hasn't been a change to the data collection. With this in mind, I assume changes are due to a change in the underlying feature distribution. I'd like to quantify this change over a series of datasets that I have.

The datasets are large, on the order of $10,000-100,000$ rows in size with $250$ columns.

I've heard about KL Divergence and think it could be a good measure of the difference between the feature distributions of the new and old datasets.

### Question

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence?useskin=vector#Statistics):

> In mathematical statistics, the Kullback–Leibler divergence (also called relative entropy and I-divergence), denoted $D_{\text{KL}}(P\parallel Q)$, is a type of statistical distance: a measure of how one probability distribution P is different from a second...

I've [read](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/the-best-way-to-calculate-variations-between-2-datasets) that [KL Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence?useskin=vector#Statistics) is a good way to calculate the difference between multi-variable datasets, please see related questions for an example.

However, as KL Divergence explains the difference between probability distributions, I assume I'll have to transform my datasets into probability distributions of some form.

I haven't been able to find a standard way of doing this, but I have two ideas:

1. **Compare feature by feature.** Bin feature values and use the bin size to calculate the probability of each bin. Use the bins in both datasets to calculate KL Divergence.
2. **Compare everything.** Cluster all the samples in each dataset and get a probability for each cluster. Use those cluster probabilities to calculate KL Divergence.

Are these ideas sensible? Or is there a standard way of calculating KL Divergence that I haven't been able to find yet?

**Related Questions:**

1. [Data Science Stack Exchange question on calculating the variation between datasets.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/the-best-way-to-calculate-variations-between-2-datasets)

Comment: Where did you read that? $D_{KL}$ is not symmetric and it will be sensible to your choice of distribution. Why do you believe that computing it will allow your to calculate how different two datasets are? If you measure $D_{KL}=10$, how would you interpret that?

Comment: I read it all over the place! But the first couple of sentences in wikipedia seem to indicate the same thing! I've got an initial distribution and several others that I want to compare to. So $D_{KL}$ will be a relative measure in the feature by feature case (compared across features), and a relative measure in both cases compared across datasets. Presumably, the lower the metric the less divergence.

Comment: What would you use instead?

Comment: "Presumably, the lower the metric the less divergence." Sure, but what do you conclude from any number that's not 0 or infinite?

Comment: "What would you use instead?" - that would require more details on the problem to answer

Comment: I want to know which features have changed the most and which datasets have changed the most. So the metric is **relative**, I'm not going to interpret the absolute value as anything. Although, isn't there a way to make $D_{KL}$ go from zero to one? That would make it far easier to draw a conclusion.

Comment: What do you need to know? I'm working on Tabular data, it has ~250 columns, all of it has been encoded into a numerical format. There is some one hot encoding. What else would be helpful for you to give a recommendation? Why wouldn't KL Divergence work in this case?

Comment: *"Are these ideas sensible?"* They could be, but it can't be said definitely without knowing what the datasets mean and what the point is of the comparison.

Comment: *"Or is there a standard way of calculating KL Divergence that I haven't been able to find yet?"* The standard way is to apply it to probability distributions. What you are doing might be possible, but it has a nonstandard extra step (converting to a probability density) and it is unclear what you consider the equivalent probability distribution (you suggest binning, but there are other ways like fitting a density distribution).

Comment: *"I read it all over the place"* then it shouldn't be too hard to give a quote from a source. *"the first couple of sentences in wikipedia"* the first sentences of *which* Wikipedia?

Comment: "I want to know which features have changed the most" - you could directly compare the empirical EDFs of individual features, as in the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, for example

Comment: *"have changed the most"* KL divergence looks purely to the probabilities. If it is relevant over which distances (in terms of the underlying feature variables) the changes occur, then this does not show in the KL divergence. The [earth movers distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) would be more appropriate. So, that's an example why the context is important in order to say anything about whether or not the ideas are sensible.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I'd rather not fit a density distribution. I accept that may be a cleaner way of doing it, but I don't have the time to check the shape of every distribution!

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I'll add the quote from Wikipedia. The question has a link to the article. I've also got a potentially related section with a question and answer that says KL can give you the variation between datasets. Happy to be wrong though, I don't care. I just want to calculate the variation!

Comment: @Connor fitting a density distribution can also be as simple as fitting some [kernel smoother](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother). The main point is that we can not judge these sort of things for you without background information. *"Binning of feature values, is that sensible?"*, we have no information to make decisions about that.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus what do you need to know? I'm happy to update my question, but I have no idea what information is pertinent.

Comment: @Connor The background of the problem. What are the datasets representing (Ideally also some visualisation of the data itself)? What is the reason for making the comparison? ---- The general answer to your question is that your described method is not neccesarily non-sensible. But, whether it is sensible or non-sensible for your *particular* case, that we can not judge.

Comment: Also note the example that I gave of the alternative earth movers distance. You need to give information that allows to make decisions between the different types of distance measures, and different ways to describe your data as a distribution. There are many different ways to express 'change'. What *sort* of change you are looking for is not clear.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I can't upload visualisations right now. But I have added background to the question so it's clear why I'm asking it. Is that reasonable? I can't go into much detail on what the model is for.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Okay, does my update help you understand what change I'm looking for? Or do I need to add more information? I hadn't given the change much thought until you mentioned it, but I guess I'm looking for univariate changes, so maybe the feature by feature method works best?

Comment: *"due to a drift in the feature distribution"* is this drift a type of extrapolation, and entirely new features that were not (much) in the training set, or is it only a change in balance? KL divergence only measures a change in balance. If some features have changed, then the magnitude of the changes are irrelevant for KL divergence (if some new sample has a previously unseen value, not in the training data, then KL divergence just recognises it as unseen, but the actual value itself, whether it is far away or close, is irrelevant).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus There are no new features, so a change in balance. Which I take from your answer means KL Divergence is acceptable?

Comment: @Connor no new features, but new values instead? KL divergence only tells you that the distributions have redistributed, but there is no information over the difference in the values that have shifted. When a 10 changes in a 10.1 or in a 100, it is the same to divergence if the density at those values is equal.

Comment: Example: the following distribution $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ will result in the same divergence relating to $X$ $$P(X=5) = 0.4 \qquad P(X=10) = 0.4 \qquad P(X=15) = 0.1 \qquad P(X=20) = 0.1 $$  $$P(Y_1=5) = 0.3 \qquad P(Y_1=10) = 0.4 \qquad P(Y_1=15) = 0.1 \qquad P(Y_1=20) = 0.2 $$ $$P(Y_2=5) = 0.4 \qquad P(Y_2=10) = 0.3 \qquad P(Y_2=15) = 0.2 \qquad P(Y_2=20) = 0.1 $$ when we shift probability mass from a place with 0.4 to a place with 0.1 such that it changes into 0.3 to 0.2, then KL divergence doesn't care about the underlying values and the distance between those values.

Comment: I will try to see if I can get my comments into an answer and make it a bit more constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are these ideas sensible? Or is there a standard way of calculating KL Divergence that I haven't been able to find yet?

The standard way to compute the (symmetric) Kullback-Leibler divergence is to apply the formula

$$\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}_P} P(x) \log\left( \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \right) + \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}_Q} Q(x) \log\left( \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \right) $$

where $P$ and $Q$ are the probabilities of the events $x$ and the sum is taken over the space of all events $\mathcal{X}$ with non-zero probability.

Or an equivalent for densities

$$\int_{x \in \mathcal{X}_P} f(x) \log\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) \, dx + \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}_Q} g(x) \log\left( \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right) \, dx $$

**The non-standard step is how you obtain the distributions for your data.**

- **1. Binning.** This is the simple way to do it. It is especially known to be used in creating histograms. All the typical complications/problems with histograms also apply here. If you have very low numbers in the bins then the method does not work well. And you may even get bins with zero probability such that the divergence becomes infinite. See the below example with two samples from a standard normal distribution

  [image: infinite divergence due to bins with zero probability]
- **1a. kernel smoother** an alternative to binning and histograms, is to fit a some kernel smoother to the data. With the vanilla smoothener `density` from R then the image above would become.

  [image: example with density]
  For this example 0.1081095 is the divergence.

2. **Using class probabilities.** This can work as well. One way to do this is to use a nearest neighbours algorithm that computes the ratio $P(x)/Q(x)$ and sum this over all points.

   For the example this could go like the following in R code

   ```
   ### generate data
   set.seed(1)
   x = rnorm(100)
   y = rnorm(100)
   z = c(x,y)

   ### 15 compute nearest neighbours 
   M = outer(z,z, "-")    # matrix with distances
   M = abs(M)
   M2 = apply(M,1,order)  # get id's of closest neighbour 

   ## compute probabilities 
   p2 = colSums(M2[1:15,]>100) #compute id 's of class y
   odds1 = p2/(15-p2)          # compute odds

   ## divergence
   sum(log(1/odds1[1:100]))/100+
   sum(log(odds1[101:200]))/100
   ```

   This gives a divergence of 0.2482063

   I made a quick and dirty computation if the nearest neighbours, possibly there is some ready to use function with an algorithm that can be applied here. The basic principle is clear.

   A problem here is that some probabilities $P$ and $Q$ might become zero and the divergence becomes infinite. The kernel smoother does not have this disadvantage and is similar to a nearest neighbours classification.
3. **Fit a distribution.** In some problems you could fit some parametric distribution.

Comment: This answer is purely about the question in the title, how to compute the divergence. Whether or not it makes sense for your case to apply it is another issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the work you put into this answer! It's very helpful.

Comment: Where does the name "kernel smoother" come from? I know a kernel in machine learning can mean a weighting function, is the idea similar in this situation?

Comment: I've updated my question to indicate the size of the datasets I'm talking about! Apologies for not providing that upfront. I have large datasets, so with correctly chosen boundaries, binning shouldn't be an issue. However, I like the kernel smoother you've shown there, would you say a kernel smoother is generally better than binning, even when you have a lot of samples like I do?

Comment: @connor I gave a link in the comments https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother . Why it is called kernel I am not sure. I have tried before to look into the etymology but I did not have much success as a lot of methods refer to 'kernel'.

Comment: @Connor the kernel smoother in the example of this question computes in every point of the curve a sum of contributions from each data point (it is a sort of convolution, and that relates to this term 'kernel'). So you get a lot of computations when your curve is computed for a large space and when you have many points. But points far away should not contribute a lot and you might combine something like nearest neighbours with the distance to those neighbours to get a sort of estimate. (Maybe there exists something like 'wheighted nearest neighbours'?)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you are asking the *wrong* question, the fundamental issue is identifying why the model is performing worse (problem X in wikipedia), instead you are asking about developing metrics to calculate difference between two multidimensional data sets(problem Y in wikipedia).
As commenters have pointed out the difference in KL divergence is hard to interpret.

Having found out the actual question is identifying why the model is performing worse, then the direct issue with KL (apart from complexities in calculating it), is that there is no link to the dependent variable.  eg if only one variable impacts the model performance, then KL divergence across all the variables will not be very discriminatory.

So what I am suggesting you do is analyse the distribution of your unthresholded model predictions - this links inputs more directly to model performance - eg what proportion of inputs were assigned an output of 30% -35% (from 0 - 100%). These are the "same" inputs in terms of your model. So look at how this distribution has changed over time . Since this is 1 dimensional it's easier to analyse and visualise.

This will give you an idea if the input data distribution has changed over time. (and you could even use KL divergence on it if you so wished, but I suspect it won't be useful vs just a regular histogram)

An alternative explanation is not that the independent data distribution has changed, but the input-output relationship has changed.

you can analyse this using a probability calibration curve. see eg [why-model-calibration-matters-and-how.html](https://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2021/04/why-model-calibration-matters-and-how.html).  I am not advocating you add a calibration step to your model (as in that article) though, just create a plot showing the true probability for each binned output value (eg 30-35% etc). Compare the plot you get when the model
was performing well, vs when the model was performing worse.[It doesn't really matter whether the original dataset was well calibrated, just if there is a difference to the new data set]

In the ideal case, either the predicted value distribution changes, but calibration curve stays same or vice versa - to allow you to identify which of these is the reason. Obviously, chances are that both have changed!

For some metrics you could even analyse the relative impact of each (if you can adjust your metric to takes as input probability and binned prediction output and actual probability for that bin).

Comment: What's an "xy problem"? I've had a look at my model thresholds for similar performance across time. From them, it seems the necessary threshold to classify correctly shifts downwards. Does that indicate a data drift?

What are calibration plots?

Comment: @Connor the [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is when you are asking about a problem $x$ but are actually interested in problem $y$. Such questions may sometimes be confusing because the problem $x$ is not always well motivated and unclear (the question generates additional questions like 'why do you want to solve $x$?' or 'what is the point of $x$?). It can be better to ask about $y$ more directly or at least clarify that problem $x$ has problem $y$ as underlying problem.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thank you! Apologies for that. I am genuinely interested in KL Divergence, but I suppose without knowing why I'm interested you can't use your domain knowledge to explain whether it's okay/ useful to be interested. Is that about right?

Comment: @Connor yes, that is very common: if you don't know the answer to your question, then it might be difficult to ask the question in a correct way. In cases that this becomes a difficulty, explaining the underlying problem in simple English, can often help others to understand what the problem is about.

Comment: @Connor "From them, it seems the necessary threshold to classify correctly shifts downwards.Does that indicate a data drift?" - I don't think so.  This is precisely why I am suggesting looking separately at prediction variable *and* calibration plot.  If you need to change the threshold it may be because of data drift or because of model drift.

Comment: @seanv507 Isn't data drift a form of model drift? Also, what is the calibration plot? How my model performs vs the threshold?

Comment: An alternative explanation is not that the independent data distribution has changed (data drift), but the input-output relationship has changed (model or concept drift).
here is another link showing calibration plots https://wttech.blog/blog/2021/a-guide-to-model-calibration/